# Proper hand placement for chest flys?

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, chest

I was doing butterfly chest excercise with machine as shown [here](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/main/popup/name/butterfly)

But, my trainer said I am doing it wrong as my hands should be straight when coming to front. While earlier, my elbow was bent when I bring my hands together. I was able to do 110 pounds with my prior technique. However, with the technique told by trainer I was hardly able to do 60 pound. So, if the trainer told me the correct form, which I think he did, which muscle was I training earlier? He told me it was shoulders, but, I have my doubts. Can someone clarify proper method of butterfly fly on this machine?

Comment: Is your trainer certified?  Without seeing you perform the exercise, it's difficult to comment on your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question since you did not describe your form very well.  The picture provided is the correct technique, and I don't know what your trainer is telling you.

Chest flys primarily target the chest.  Secondary muscles used in this exercise include the front deltoids and the biceps.  Biceps act only as a stabilizer.

The chest is much bigger than the front deltoids, so if you are lifting less weight, chances are that you're using your deltoids.  This means that you are performing the exercise incorrectly.

Go by feel.  If you feel a squeeze in the middle of your chest, you're on the right track.  If your shoulders are burning, or even in pain, then you're probably doing it wrong.

P.S.  Chest flys are an *accessory* movement.  You shouldn't really be concerned with how much weight you're moving.  Stick to bench presses to build strength.